# Python: Pandas dataframe get the year to which the week number belongs and not the year of the date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv-file: https://data.rivm.nl/covid-19/COVID-19_aantallen_gemeente_per_dag.csv

I want to use it to provide insight into the corona deaths per week.

> ```
>   df = pd.read_csv("covid.csv", error_bad_lines=False, sep=";")
>   df = df.loc[df['Deceased'] > 0]
>   df["Date_of_publication"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date_of_publication"])
>   df["Week"] = df["Date_of_publication"].dt.isocalendar().week
>   df["Year"] = df["Date_of_publication"].dt.year
>   df = df[["Week", "Year", "Municipality_name", "Deceased"]]
>   df = df.groupby(by=["Week", "Year", "Municipality_name"]).agg({"Deceased" : "sum"})
>   df = df.sort_values(by=["Year", "Week"])
>   print(df)
> ```

Everything seems to be working fine except for the first 3 days of 2021. The first 3 days of 2021 are part of the last week (53) of 2020: http://week-number.net/calendar-with-week-numbers-2021.html.

When I print the dataframe this is the result:

> ```
>  53   2021 Winterswijk               1
>            Woudenberg                1
>            Zaanstad                  1
>            Zeist                     2
>            Zutphen                   1
> ```

So basically what I'm looking for is a way where this line returns the year of the week number and not the year of the date:

> ```
>   df["Year"] = df["Date_of_publication"].dt.year
> ```

Comment: Thankyou for asking this, I had exactly the same problem :)

Comment: @user6395790 See if any further clarification of the answer required.  If no, please remember to accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dt.isocalendar().year` to setup `df["Year"]`:

```
df["Year"] = df["Date_of_publication"].dt.isocalendar().year
```

You will get year 2020 for date of 2021-01-01 but will get back to year 2021 for date of 2021-01-04 by this.

This is just similar  to how you used `dt.isocalendar().week` for setting up `df["Week"]`.  Since they are both basing on the same tuple `(year, week, day)` returned by `dt.isocalendar()`, they would always be in sync.

### Demo

```
date_s = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', periods=5, freq='1D'))

date_s

    0
0   2021-01-01
1   2021-01-02
2   2021-01-03
3   2021-01-04
4   2021-01-05

date_s.dt.isocalendar()

   year  week  day
0  2020    53    5
1  2020    53    6
2  2020    53    7
3  2021     1    1
4  2021     1    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply subtract the two dates and then divide the days attribute of the timedelta object by 7.

For example, this is the current week we are on now.

```
time_delta = (dt.datetime.today() - dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1))
```

The output is a datetime timedelta object

```
datetime.timedelta(days=75, seconds=84904, microseconds=144959)
```

For your problem, you'd do something like this

```
time_delta = int((df["Date_of_publication"] - df["Year"].days / 7)
```

The output would be a number that is the current week since date_of_publication